# Замена значения в таблице, как создать обработчик запроса на PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос вида

```
UPDATE `gb_ptich` SET `pay_status` = REPLACE(`pay_status`, '0', '1')
```

нужно чтобы он выполнялся при клике на ссылку `<a href="#">Обновить</a>`

Как это сделать посредством PHP?

Comment: Делаешь кнопку, вешаешь обработчик, посылаешь запрос. Какие трудности?

Comment: если бы я умел - не спрашивал бы, схема понятна, но спасибо за ответ

Comment: Вообще-то это был вопрос. Тоесть что конкретно не понятно

Comment: Конкретно пример кода нужен =(

Comment: Так полно примеров кругом. Можно сделать форму на html с запросом. Можно отправить запрос get или post с помощью ajax или xhr. Исходя из заголовок вопроса ты хочешь создать именно обработчик нажатия кнопки и отправки запроса, а в метках я вижу только php и mysql. Так что конкретно требуется?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом: пусть форма расположена в файле index.html и содержит клиентскую часть мини-приложения (ссылку и AJAX-обвязку для нее)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
  <head>
  <title>Обновление таблицы</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" >
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Назначить обработчики события click
    // после загрузки документа
    $(function(){
      $("a").on("click", function(){
        // Отправляем AJAX-запрос
        $.post("handler.php");
      })
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#">Обновить</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Как видно AJAX-запрос отправляется файлу handler.php, который может содержать следующий код, для выполнения UPDATE-запроса (используется расширение PDO)

```
<?php
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
      'root',
      '',
      [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    $query = "UPDATE
                `gb_ptich`
              SET
                `pay_status` = REPLACE(`pay_status`, '0', '1')";
    $pdo->exec($query);
    header('location: /');
    exit();
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все есть, заработало =)

Comment: @Doofy, согласен, не внимательно почитал, поправил клиентскую часть на минимальный AJAX.

Comment: @cheops, да часто автор не может задать правильно вопрос что ему нужно. А те, кто отвечают на вопросы, видать, телепаты. Или автор просто ленивый. *Напишите мне, пожалуйста, такую функцию, а ответ я отмечу галочкой*. И вот пока выясняешь у автора что ему нужно, другие уже кидаются отвечать

Comment: @cheops, хоть бы ответ оформил как полагается. Отдели хотябы php от html. Раз уж jquery подключил, можно было одной строчкой через `$.post` сделать

Comment: @Doofy, спасибо за замечание, поправил ответ.

Comment: Сорри но минус. Надо быть последовательным html->form->request . И наче новички начнут пихать не нужные ajax. Конкретно в этом примере даные не приходят от обработчика. И не выполняються действий после завершения запроса. Что собствену излишне человеку придеться обновить страницу самому.

Comment: @Naumov, ещё новички часто не могут обойтись без jquery и при ответе могут не понять его и не отметить правильным

Comment: @Naumov я изначально сделал форму, но переработал пример, так как в вопросе идет речь об <a href="#">Обновить</a>, а не об форме. Цепочка html->form->request это уже ваше предположение/предложение, если вы хотите увидеть решение по этой цепочке, пожалуйста задайте свой собственный вопрос - с удовольствием приведу такой пример. Если вы сами знаете как лучше ответить на данный вопрос, вы можете разместить рядом свое собственное решение.

Comment: @cheops с точки зренея задавшего вопрос, вы ответили правильно. Но с моей точки зрения ответ неверен, на основание доводов выше. Извините еще раз за минус ( но это мое субъективное мнение )